# Stubborn unaligned input field

Tags: css

theredarmy.ca

Unable to properly align:

```
Full name input field
```

Even tried via:

```
Position: absolute;
```

No luck.

Any idea besides the obvious?

Comment: Hey Edward, can you [edit] your question and write it in a sentence form? If you write a proper question you get a proper answer. Check [ask] if you need more help, and don't forget to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is set to remove the margin from the first child of the form tag.

```
  signup-form > :first-child {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
```

Either remove that or alter it to coincide with the other (div) CSS:

```
 signup-form > :first-child {
            margin: 0 0 0 1em;
        }
```

Although, for me, removing it would be the best option if the first child doesn't need special properties.

---

In the future it is best to provide the markup rather than random text to copy/paste a link. Questions should be self-contained and *not* require users to visit some other link. It is acceptable to link to things like [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) though. There you can create working samples of code which are not dependent upon some other domain, or site, remaining active in the future.

Comment: Where is that code exactly? I can't find signup-form > :first-child ...

Comment: Either in index or stylesheet

Comment: Disregard, a quick Ctrl+F in style sheet got it. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Yeah I was going to post that its int eh stylesheet under the /* -- Sign up form -- */

Comment: Any idea how yo align center my footer? (If you'd prefer I'll open another question.)

Comment: @EdwardOak For many CSS/HTML related questions http://StackOverflow.com is a better stack site. It'll already have a lot of answers.

Comment: I can't meet their question standards. Thanks. Thumb down flood, no leads , comments or answers. Worst experience as a new poster, not going back there unless it's to try a slow Loris on it. Been 24h and I'm still salty.

Comment: Well, be aware, question standards here aren't a great deal lower. We may be a tad more lax with CSS/HTML questions because they aren't the "norm" here. But there's a high probability they can be closed and referred to StackOverflow. We don't have things like the inline fiddle editor or even really markup control to any great degree. I do completely understand StackOverflow from a new user perspective though. They aren't really very friendly or inviting in many ways.

Comment: To be fair, I simply want to make my landing page work, I work my magic with my SMS API and backend server. I'm sorry if my questions aren't properly asked/formulated. Then again, having standards for questions pretty much restricts the ability for coding illiterates like me to go forward.

Comment: Feel free to have my question removed if it hinders the amount of quality posts. Also, you already directly answered and fixed my issue. Send me a BTC address and I'll send you $20. I don't mind paying, but I've had bad experiences outsourcing work and overall, not doing it myself.

Comment: Nah `:)` I don't post here to earn anything. The offer is very generous though.

Comment: Have a good one buddy, wish me luck for footer 